# Transform hexadecimal representation to unicode

Tags: unix, sed, unicode, utf-8

I'm dealing with very big files (~10Gb) containing word with ascii representation of unicode :

```
Nuray \u00d6zdemir
Erol \u010colakovi\u0107 \u0160ehi\u0107
```

I want to tranform them into unicode before inserting them into a database, like this :

```
Nuray Özdemir
Erol Čolaković Šehić
```

I've seen how [to do it with vim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2303) but it's very slow for very large file. I thought copy/paste of the regex would be OK but it's not.

I actually get things like this:

```
$ echo "Nuray \u00d6zdemir" | sed -E 's/\\\u(.)(.)(.)(.)/\x\1\x\2\x\3\x\4/g'
Nuray x0x0xdx6zdemir
```

**How can I concatenate the `\x` and the value of `\1` `\2`...?**

I don't want to use `echo` or an external program due to the size of the file, I want something efficient.

Comment: what DB do you use? You might be able to do the conversion at the insertion step!!!

Comment: I use mongoDB (mongoimport)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the unicodes in your file are within BMP (16bit), how about:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN {binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8")} s/\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/chr(hex($1))/ge' input_file > output_file
```

Output:

```
Nuray Özdemir
Erol Čolaković Šehić
```

I have generated a 6Gb file to test the speed efficiency.
It took approx. 10 minutes to process the entire file on my 6 year old laptop.
I hope it will be acceptable to you.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a mongoDB expert at all but what I can tell you is the following:

If there is a way to do it at the import directly within the DB engine, this solution should be used, now if this feature is not available.

You can use either use a naive approach to solve it:

```
while read -r line; do echo -e "$line"; done < input_file
```

**INPUT:**

```
cat input_file
Nuray \u00d6zdemir
Erol \u010colakovi\u0107 \u0160ehi\u0107
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Nuray Özdemir
Erol Čolaković Šehić
```

But as you have spotted yourself the call to `echo -e` at each line will create a resource intensive change of context (generate a sub-process for `echo` -> memory allocation, new entry in the processes table, priority management, switching back to the parent process) that is not efficient for 10GB files.

Or go for a smarter approach using tools that should be available in your distro example:

```
whatis ascii2uni 
ascii2uni (1)        - convert 7-bit ASCII representations to UTF-8 Unicode
```

Command:

```
ascii2uni -a U -q input_file 
Nuray Özdemir
Erol Čolaković ᘎhić
```

You can also split (ex `split` command) the input file in pieces, run in parallel the conversion step on each sub file, and import each converted pieces as soon as it is available to shorten the total execution time.